# ¿Como puedo ubicar barcos aleatoriamente en un tablero de batalla naval en java?

Tags: java

compañeros, tengo una duda de como crear un codigo para generar tablero de batalla naval(no todo el juego) y ubicar los barcos de forma aleatoria donde "11111" es el portaaviones, "222" es el barco y "33" es la fragata, debo decir que necesito ubicar un porta aviones, dos barcos y dos fragatas, consiste en hacerlos con arrays en java, por favor necesito una ayudita.

```
Random Ram = new Random();

        int Filas, Columnas; //variables filas
        String matriz[][];

        matriz = new String[15][15];// Creacion matriz

        String alphabet = ("1"+"1"+"1"+"1"+"1"+"2"+"2"+"2"+"2"+"2"+"2"+"3"+"3"+"3"+"3");//

        List<String> palabrasSeparadas = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(alphabet.split(";"))); // 

        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length && !palabrasSeparadas.isEmpty(); i++) { //2 ciclos para recorrer matriz 
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length && !palabrasSeparadas.isEmpty(); j++) { 
                int r = Ram.nextInt(palabrasSeparadas.size());
                matriz[i][j] = palabrasSeparadas.get(r); //llena la matriz con las palabras de manera aleatoria
                palabrasSeparadas.remove(r);    // Se elimina de la lista para que no se repita
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta, amigo?

Comment: No entiendo la utilidad de tu variable `alphabet`, tampoco comprendo el porqué no usar una estructura de datos definida (una clase). ¿O es un ejercicio en el que aún no les han enseñado POO y sólo se pueden usar matrices y/o arrays?

Comment: Agrega una condición para que chequee si en `matriz[i][j]` existe un elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es lo que llamo una respuesta retardada...
El primer método es el encargado de colocar los barcos en el tablero, los otros métodos, son auxiliares de este.

Para saber si puede ubicarse en la posición determinada, debemos verificar que todas las posiciones que va a ocupar estén vacías, así como todas las que lo rodean, gráficamente sería algo así:

```
#######
#55555#
#######
```

siendo "5" partes del barco y "#" las casillas que lo rodean

```
   // recibe el tamaño del tablero y una matriz con los barcos
String[][] ubicarBarcos( int lado, String barcos[][] ) {
   String tablero[][] = new String[ lado ][ lado ];
   rellena( tablero );
   int cual = 0;
   Random Ram = new Random();
   int tamaño = tablero[ 0 ].length;

      // cada fila de la matriz, representa un barco
   while( cual < barcos.length ) {

        // determinamos si va en horizontal o vertical
      int direccion = Ram.nextInt( 2 );
      int tamañoBarco = barcos[ cual ].length;

        // generamos la posición inicial dentro del rango permitido
      int x = Ram.nextInt( tamaño - tamañoBarco +1 );
      int y = Ram.nextInt( tamaño - tamañoBarco +1 );

         // "tamañoI" y "tamañoK" toman el valor del lado del rectángulo que debemos
         // verificar, para la altura y el ancho respectivamente
         // "subei" y "subek" se usan para saber (a la hora de imprimir el barco, 
         // en que sentido a de avanzar,"k" e "i" son las posiciones desde las 
         // que se empieza a iterar
      
      int tamañoI = 3, tamañoK = 3, k = x -1, i = y -1, subek = 0, subei = 0;        
      

         // esta parte del código, se encarga de instanciar los valores de las variables, 
         // en función de la dirección, si estamos en horizontal, la altura 
         // debería ser "3", a menos que "y" sea cero, en cuyo caso debe ser "2", 
         // el ancho debe ser igual al largo del barco más "2", salvo que "x" 
         // sea "0" en cuyo caso deberá ser largo del barco + "1". 
    
      if( direccion == 0 ) {   // horizontal
         tamañoK += tamañoBarco - 1;
         subek = 1;
      }
      else {
         tamañoI += tamañoBarco - 1;
         subei = 1;
      }
      if( x == 0 ) {
         k = x;
         tamañoK -= 1;
      }
      if( y == 0 ) {
         i = y;
         tamañoI -= 1;
      }
 
      boolean reinicia = false;
        
         // usamos esta variable a modo de memoria para guardar el valor de "k"
      int mem = k;

         // creamos las condiciones de parada del los for
      int condicionI = i + tamañoI;
      int condicionK = k + tamañoK;
      for( ; i < condicionI  && i < tamaño; i++ ) {
         k = mem;
         for( ; k < condicionK && k < tamaño; k++ ) {    

               // si la posición no está vacía, pasamos "reinicia" a "true" para 
               // evitar que grabe el barco y salimos del for interno
            if( ! tablero[ i ][ k ].equals( " " )) { 
               reinicia = true;
               break;
            }               
         }
      }

         // si no encontró posiciones ocupadas, entra en el if, toma el valor de 
         // la letra del barco, y modifica el valor contenido en las posiciones
      if( !reinicia ) {
         String letra = barcos[ cual ][ 0 ];
         for( i = y, k = x; i < y + tamañoBarco && k < x + tamañoBarco; i += subei, k += subek ) {
            tablero[ i ][ k ] = letra;
         }
         cual++;
      }
   }
   return tablero;
}    

void rellena( String array[][] ) {
   for( int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
      for( int j = 0; j < array.length; j++ ) {
         array[ i ][ j ] = " ";
      }
   }
}

String barcos[][] = {
   { "5", "5", "5", "5", "5" }, { "4", "4", "4", "4", },
   { "4", "4", "4", "4", }, { "3", "3", "3" }, { "3", "3", "3" },
   { "3", "3", "3" }, { "2", "2" }, { "2", "2" }, { "2", "2" },
   { "2", "2" }, { "1" }, { "1" }, { "1" }, { "1" }, { "1" }
};
```

Nota: es muy probable, que si se usa un tamaño pequeño de tablero (em relación a la cantidad y longitud de los barcos) se entre en un bucle infinito... obrar con precaución, o agregar un límite a las iteraciones del while, con la matriz de barcos que tenemos arriba, un tablero de "15x15" no da problemas, a medida que achicamos el lado...